# selecting columns with tables created using double quotation fail

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, apache-superset

I connected a postgresql database to Apache Superset and am playing around with their SQL editor. I'm running into a problem where I cannot do a left join between two tables with an associated id.

```
SELECT id, profile_name FROM "ProductionRun"
LEFT JOIN "StatsAssociation" ON "ProductionRun".id = "StatsAssociation".production_run_id;
```

Is my above syntax correct? The tables must be referenced with double quotation because they are created case sensitive. This returns only the `id` and `profile_name` columns of `ProductionRun` table without joining with `StatsAssociation` table.

I created the tables using sqlalchemy and here are the table schema:

ProductionRun

```
class ProductionRun(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'ProductionRun'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    profile_name = Column(String, nullable=False)
```

StatsAssociation

```
class StatsAssociation(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'StatsAssociation'

    production_run_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('ProductionRun.id'), primary_key=True)
    stats_package_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('StatsPackage.id'), unique=True, nullable=False)

    stats_package = relationship('StatsPackage', back_populates='stats_association', cascade='all,delete')
    production_run = relationship('ProductionRun', back_populates='stats_association')
```

When I view the tables, they both exist and `StatsAssociation` has `production_run_id` column which shares the same ids as `ProductionRun`.

Comment: You're not specifying any column from the "StatsAssociation" table, so it is expected that nothing would show up. To get columns in the output of the SELECT query, you need to list them. For example, and just to start you off: `SELECT id, profile_name, production_run_id FROM ...` where `...` is the rest of your query.

Comment: could you change ^ to an answer? I am new to SQL so this isn't as obvious as it seems.

Comment: Sure thing, and no worries. We were all new once :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was originally posted as a comment.

You're not specifying any column from the "StatsAssociation" table, so it is expected that nothing would show up. To get columns in the output of the SELECT query, you need to list them -- the only exception that I can currently think of being if you use `"TableName".*` or `*` in SELECT.

For example, and just to start you off:

```
SELECT id, profile_name, production_run_id 
FROM ...
```

where `...` is the rest of your query.